# Touches in Cocos2d + Box2d - Iphone Game Development

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, touches

I have a problem with touches on the iPhone5.
The problem lies within the method below:

```
- (void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   // Here I do something
}
```

Here is the image - http://postimg.org/image/qrokz07g1/

Touches work only in green area. In the red area, it doesn't work.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: We'll need more info than that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should add `Default-568h@2x.png` image (along with the default launcher images) to your project in order to enable the iphone 5 resolution support. Otherwise your screen will be treated by `cocos2d` like standard iphone 4 screen centered on your iphone 5 screen (and the red sections of course will be ignored).